# How to upload server with the nodemailer service to godaddy live hosting?

Tags: reactjs, nodemailer

i have a react application and that has a server folder inside it to configure the contact form. while testing locally with local host it working but when uploaded online the form isn't working. I am new to react js and also at the backend programming. so please can anyone help me with this.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Snackbar from '@mui/material/Snackbar';
import MuiAlert from '@mui/material/Alert';
import 'aos/dist/aos.css';
import AOS from 'aos';
AOS.init();

const Alert = React.forwardRef(function Alert(props, ref) {
  return <MuiAlert elevation={6} ref={ref} variant="filled" {...props} />;
});

const ContactForm = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    firstName: '',
    email: '',
    phone: '',
    message: ''
  });

  const [snackbar, setSnackbar] = useState({
    open: false,
    message: '',
    severity: 'success'
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const handleSnackbarClose = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason === 'clickaway') {
      return;
    }
    setSnackbar({ ...snackbar, open: false });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const response = await axios.post('https://localhost:3001/api/contact', formData);
      console.log(response.data);

      setSnackbar({ open: true, message: 'Message sent successfully!', severity: 'success' });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error submitting form:', error.response.data);

      setSnackbar({ open: true, message: 'An error occurred. Please try again later.', severity: 'error' });
    }
  };

  return (
    <section id="contact" className="contact-us" data-aos="fade-up">
      <div className="container">
        <h6 className="sub-heading">Contact Us</h6>
        <h2 className="mb-5">Get in Touch <span className="heading-animate">with Us</span></h2>
        <div className="col-lg-12">
          <div className="contact-us-content">
            <form id="contact-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit} netlify>
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-lg-12">
                  <fieldset>
                    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" onChange={handleChange} autoComplete="on" required />
                  </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div className="col-lg-12">
                  <fieldset>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your E-mail" onChange={handleChange} autoComplete="on" required />
                  </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div className="col-lg-12">
                  <fieldset>
                    <input type="text" name="phone" id="number" placeholder="Your Phone Number" onChange={handleChange} autoComplete="on" required />
                  </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div className="col-lg-12">
                  <fieldset>
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your Message" onChange={handleChange} required></textarea>
                  </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div className="col-lg-12">
                  <fieldset>
                    <button type="submit" id="form-submit" className="orange-button">Send Message</button>
                  </fieldset>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
            <Snackbar open={snackbar.open} autoHideDuration={6000} onClose={handleSnackbarClose}>
              <Alert onClose={handleSnackbarClose} severity={snackbar.severity}>
                {snackbar.message}
              </Alert>
            </Snackbar>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default ContactForm;
```

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const { json, urlencoded } = require('express');

dotenv.config();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(json());
app.use(urlencoded({ extended: false }));

const contactEmail = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "smtpout.secureserver.net",
  secure: true,
  port: 465,
  auth: {
    user: process.env.EMAIL_ADDRESS,
    pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS
  }
});


contactEmail.verify((error) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Ready to send');
  }
});

app.post('/api/contact', (req, res) => {
  const { firstName, email, message, phone } = req.body;
  const mail = {
    from: email,
    to: process.env.EMAIL_ADDRESS,
    subject: 'Contact Form Submission',
    html: `<p>Name: ${firstName}</p>
           <p>Email: ${email}</p>
           <p>Phone: ${phone}</p>
           <p>Message: ${message}</p>`
  };

  contactEmail.sendMail(mail, (error) => {
    if (error) {
      res.json(error);
    } else {
      res.json({ code: 200, status: 'Message Sent' });
    }
  });
});

app.post('/api/quote', (req, res) => {
  const { firstName, email, message, phone, selectedService } = req.body;
  const quoteMail = {
    from: email,
    to: process.env.EMAIL_ADDRESS,
    subject: 'Get A Quote Form Submission',
    html: `<p>Name: ${firstName}</p>
           <p>Email: ${email}</p>
           <p>Phone: ${phone}</p>
           <p>Service: ${selectedService}</p>
           <p>Message: ${message}</p>`
  };

  contactEmail.sendMail(quoteMail, (error) => {
    if (error) {
      res.json(error);
    } else {
      res.json({ code: 200, status: 'Quote Message Sent' });
    }
  });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is online on port: ${PORT}`);
});
```

i uploaded the react js code by making its producation build but dont know how to uploaded the server code and configure it

```
EMAIL_ADDRESS=xyz@gmail.com
EMAIL_PASS=********
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).